Powershell script throws error only when it is executed from codedeploy, Why?
I have windows instance that is running CodeDeploy Agent. I also have a powershell script that creates site in IIS:
Add sites to IIS
# Define parameters
$siteName = "test1"
$physicalPath = "C:\connect\MicroServices\authentication"
$applicationPool = "testPool"
$dnsName = "devteam5.localhost"
# Check if the application pool exists
$AppPoolExists = Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $applicationPool -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not $AppPoolExists) {
    Write-Host "Application Pool '$applicationPool' does not exist. Creating..."
    New-WebAppPool -Name $applicationPool
    Write-Host "Application Pool '$applicationPool' created successfully."
}
# Check if the site already exists
$siteExists = Get-Website -Name $siteName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($siteExists) {
    Write-Host "The website '$siteName' already exists in IIS. Script stopped."
    exit
}
# If site doesn't exist, create it with the DNS binding
New-WebSite -Name $siteName -PhysicalPath $physicalPath -ApplicationPool $applicationPool -HostHeader $dnsName -Port 80 -Force
Write-Host "Website '$siteName' created successfully in IIS and bound to '$dnsName'."

When I run it manually, this powershell executes without any error. But when I execute the script with codedeploy it throws error. My appspec.yml looks like:
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: /
    destination: C:\connect\MicroServices\authentication
    overwrite: true
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: automation-script1.ps1
      timeout: 3000
      runas: Administrator

It throws this error:
get-webitemstate : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 2024-04-19 11:09:16 [stderr](REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Manually running script works fine, but throws error when it runs with codedeploy. Kindly let me know why this behavior?
